# Failed to transfer data between view controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I am a newbie to Objective-c and stackOverflow. :)

I have created 2 view controllers which are connected by a segue called "showDetailSegue".

In the LPLviewcontroller1, I have a sentence property, which I use to set the text in the textview in LPLviewcontroller1, and I want to use segue to set the value of sentence property in LPLviewcontroller. Moreover, I have a button on the LPLviewcontroller which can perform the "showDetailSegue".

However, the program stops at

```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([LPLAppDelegate      class]));
            (program breaks here)
        }
    }
```

The System log is

```
2014-06-25 16:49:43.199 test[6322:60b] -[LPLViewController button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d43f30
2014-06-25 16:49:43.204 test[6322:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LPLViewController button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d43f30'
```

Here is LPLviewController.m

```
#import "LPLViewController.h"
#import "LPLViewController1.h"


@interface LPLViewController ()

@end

@implementation LPLViewController

- (IBAction)press:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetailSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailSegue"]){
        LPLViewController1 *controller = (LPLViewController1 *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.sentence = @"dfjlasdkfjlskdfjlksdjflkadsjf";
    }
}
@end
```

Here is LPLviewController1.m

```
#import "LPLViewController1.h"

@implementation LPLViewController1

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    _text.text = _sentence;    
}
@end
```

Comment: how you are defining the event of the button?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure without seeing the header files, but from the exception, it sounds like you did not define the property "sentence".

Answer (score -1):

You need this in the LPLViewController1.h header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sentence
```

Then use `self.sentence` in your LPLViewController1 implementation to access the value. The `prepareForSegue:sender` method is fine. But this is pretty basic Objective C stuff...